# How to run a executable with command line in Python?

Tags: python, github, anaconda, executable

I´ve installed this package: https://github.com/retostauffer/PyGFSV2, with pip. This package comes with two executables (GFSV2_get and GFSV2_bulk). But, i don´t know how to open executables in Python.

So, after instlation, the package author recomend try the installation by calling:

```
GFSV2_get --step 12 24 --level 700 850 --param tmp_pres --date 2005-01-01
```

So, i put in Anaconda Prompt the next:

```
(base) C:\Users\vrida>CD C:\Users\vrida\anaconda3\Scripts

(base) C:\Users\vrida\anaconda3\Scripts>python GFSV2_get --step 12 24 --level 700 850 --param tmp_pres --date 2005-01-01
```

But, it didn´t work. Appear this:

```
# DEBUG Loading default config file from package source.
# INFO Config file read, return.
# INFO Processing date 2005-01-01 00Z
# INFO Downloading inventory information data
# DEBUG Reading ftp://ftp.cdc.noaa.gov/Projects/Reforecast2/2005/200501/2005010100/mean/latlon\tmp_pres_2005010100_mean.grib2.inv
# ERROR Problems reading file, reason: "ftp error: URLError("ftp error: error_perm('550 Failed to change directory.')")".
# ERROR Could not download inventory file! Skip this.
# INFO Inventory empty, skip this file
# INFO Downloading inventory information data
# DEBUG Reading ftp://ftp.cdc.noaa.gov/Projects/Reforecast2/2005/200501/2005010100/sprd/latlon\tmp_pres_2005010100_sprd.grib2.inv
# ERROR Problems reading file, reason: "ftp error: URLError("ftp error: error_perm('550 Failed to change directory.')")".
# ERROR Could not download inventory file! Skip this.
# INFO Inventory empty, skip this file
```

I´m beginner in Python. So i have two questions:

1 - How to run these executables, for example with Anaconda Prompt?

2 - Could anyone make the download of the package, after try the instalation and, if sucessfull, tell me how can i make the same?

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean, exactly?  We need to see the *full error message* to be able to help you.

Comment: Why did you add `python` in front of the command? It's not there in the docs

Comment: @jasonharper i edited the question above include the full error message

Comment: @jordanm I saw a youtube video learn "How to Run Python Script using Command prompt": it learn to use python in front of the command. I tried to use this, but i´m not sure if this is the right way to run a executable in Python.

Comment: As an aside, you really shouldn’t use the Conda base environment.

Comment: @AMC So, what environment and what way should I use it for run this executables for run the test (GFSV2_get --step 12 24 --level 700 850 --param tmp_pres --date 2005-01-01) proposed by the author of the package?

Comment: @Lucas Just a new/different environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should contact the maintainer of the package. apparently the library tries to download some file via ftp, using the system file separator, \ in your case (since you are using windows), instead of /:
ftp://ftp.cdc.noaa.gov/Projects/Reforecast2/2005/200501/2005010100/mean/latlon\tmp_pres_2005010100_mean.grib2.inv

the file is accessible via anonymous ftp access using a standard ftp client. so it should be an issue with the python library.

Comment: Totally. This system file separator is the problem. I contacted the mainteiner for fix it.

Comment: The mainteiner fixed the problem with the backslash. This bug only occur in Windows Systems, as @mrxra said, and have relation with the function os.path.join. In addition, the only way that the executables run is that showed for me above, with the anaconda prompt: the real problem was the backslash, which was solved by the mainteiner. It is necessary to reinstall the package for solve the bug.